# android Custom Dialog title doesnot show

Tags: android

Im new at android app development so i was following a youtuber on making a Database, im doing same as he is, but problem is that i can make db successfully but **custom dialog title doesnt show** but error mesage & textview text is visible in my app.
Im attaching screenshot of successful code on youtube.

## [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVJYL.jpg)

```
btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean boolln=true;
            try {
                String firstname = firstnam.getText().toString();
                String lstname = lastnam.getText().toString();
                db1.insertname(firstname, lstname);

            }catch (Exception ex){
                boolln=false;
                String error=ex.toString();
                Dialog dl=new Dialog(Activity_DB.this);
                dl.setTitle("Uncuceesful");
                TextView tx=new TextView(Activity_DB.this);
                tx.setText(error);
                dl.setContentView(tx);
                dl.show();
            }finally {
                if (boolln){
                    Dialog dl1=new Dialog(Activity_DB.this);
                    dl1.setTitle("succesful? YES");
                    TextView tx=new TextView(Activity_DB.this);
                    tx.setText("sucesss");
                    dl1.setContentView(tx);
                    dl1.show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: Error was about database syntax code 1, so i corrected it,  Now only problem is i want that it should show title which is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by adding AlerDialog.builder instead of using Dialog, now it works perfectly.

```
boolln=false;
                String error=ex.toString();
                AlertDialog.Builder dl=new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity_DB.this);
                dl.setCancelable(true);
                dl.setTitle("Uncuceesful");
                dl.setMessage("No entry found. \n"+error);
                dl.show()
```